# Capital punishment in Persia

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, capital-punishment, persia

This is not a Purim joke.  Translations of the Book of Esther say the king sentenced people to be "hanged".  But modern translations (including Sefaria) say they were "impaled".  They translate "ha-etz" as "the stake", not "the tree".  Now, historians believe impalement is far more likely than hanging because that is what the Persians did.  So which is it?  And if "impaled", did earlier translators err or were simply trying not to be indelicate?

Comment: Haman prepared a 50 ammah tall stake? Are you sure this isn't a joke?

Comment: Interesting: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12924/how-did-haman-intend-to-kill-mordecai

Comment: @DoubleAA My thoughts exactly. Not to mention the word used in the Megillah (eg. Esther 8:7) is _talah_, which means "hang" to "suspend". See Jastrow's entry who provides tons of references from the Talmud and other Rabbinic literature to prove it means hang.

Comment: @ezra Many words changed their meanings between Biblical and Rabbinic Hebrew.

Comment: @ezra see Bobson's comments to the second answer in the link you provided.  Also, thanks for  posting that very interesting link.  (I think the sites would do well with a bit more collaboration on questions like these, but as noted in various meta questions, there is too much of a gap between the sites.)

Comment: @DoubleAA see  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12948/why-did-haman-build-so-tall-an-instrument-of-death

Comment: I would think that talui meant something like crucified, as that's what it means in the Torah - to tie his hands together and hang him from the wood by them, and as the targum of talui is tzaluv, and because by the rebellion of the third mar zutra seder olam says that he was talui, while modern histories of the time say crucified.

Comment: note that hanging is not just a method of death; it is an action as well. you can hang a corpse (like the ten sons of homon were). so while the hebrew word undoubtedly means hung, it does not necessarily  mean being hung with a rope by the neck

Comment: @Orangesandlemons - see tosfos where he says that the ten sons of haman were hung (not hanged) after their heads were cut off, in order for all of them to fit

Answer (score 7):

According to [Tosafos in Eiruvin 48](http://dafyomi.co.il/eruvin/tosfos/ev-ts-048.htm), Haman and his sons were hung without their heads:

> והא דכתיב בתרגום מגילת אסתר פרשנדתא איצטליב על תלת אמין וכן כולם
>   Implied question: It says in the Targum of Megilas Esther (which discusses what occupied the 50 Amos from the top of the scaffold from which Haman and his sons were hung) that Parshandasa was hung in three Amos, and likewise for all of them!
>   התם קטועי ראש הוו
>   Answer: Their heads were cut off.

So our modern day hanging of tying a rope around their necks wouldn't have worked.

See also Me'am Loez quoted [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2833315/jewish/Chapter-Nine.htm) that says, about Haman's son's at least, they were killed before they were hung.

> "ואת עשרת בני המן יתלו על העץ"
>   “And let the ten sons of Haman be hanged on the gallows.” (9:13)
>   QUESTION: They were already slain; what was her purpose in having them hung?
>   ANSWER: On the eve of the seventeenth day of Nissan, Mordechai hung Haman on the gallows (Megillah 15a, Rashi). The King ordered that his head should be protected from the birds, and he remained on the gallows for the entire year. To further humiliate the Amalikites and frighten the anti-Semites, on the thirteenth of Adarwhen his sons were slain, she asked that they be hung together. This would magnify the already existing public spectacle and convey a good lesson.
>   (ילקוט מעם לועז)

All in all we don't know if they were skewered onto the pole rotisserie style or hung on the pole crucifixion style, but from these classical Jewish sources it does not seem they had nooses tied around their necks.

Comment: Its interesting that you mention this. Indeed the majority of meforshim say that Haman's sons were killed (decapitated) prior to being hanged -EXCEPT for the Maharsha, here - https://shorturl.at/qvxIQ he explain that the text of the megillah makes it clear that they were killed in the same instant, and therefore had been hanged and killed at the same time.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ten Sons of Haman as the backdrop for this answer, there are numerous opinions that they had been decapitated prior to being hanged from the tree.

[The Maharsha](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Megillah.16b?lang=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94,%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A5%20%D7%90%27) says that they had been killed simultaneously, and it was done on a tree (not decapitation)

Furthermore, [The Meiri](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.16b.10?lang=bi&p2=Meiri_on_Megillah.16b&lang2=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93) adds that they had been hanged from the same tree, and using a single rope - which reinforces the notion that it was not a impalement, but instead was death by hanging.